# Getting data from a JSON string received from server in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a JSON string like this which is received from a server:

```
[{"AdsId":"7","AdsName":"PIC_01.JPG","AdsImage":"pic_01.jpg","AdsImageUrl":"http://www.google.com","TargetUrl":"http://www.yahoo.com","IsAllPageSupport":false,"IsArabic":false,"IsActive":true},{"AdsId":"8","AdsName":"PIC_02.JPG","AdsImage":"pic_02.jpg","AdsImageUrl":"http://www.fb.com","TargetUrl":"http://www.twitter.com","IsAllPageSupport":true,"IsArabic":false,"IsActive":true},{"AdsId":"9","AdsName":"PIC_03.JPG","AdsImage":"pic_03.jpg","AdsImageUrl":"http://www.google.com","TargetUrl":"http://www.demo.com","IsAllPageSupport":false,"IsArabic":false,"IsActive":true},{"AdsId":"10","AdsName":"PIC_04.JPG","AdsImage":"pic_04.jpg","AdsImageUrl":"http://www.sample.com","TargetUrl":"http://www.example.com","IsAllPageSupport":true,"IsArabic":false,"IsActive":true}]
```

This is a valid JSON format. But I don't know how to parse this string and retrieve the values inside this JSON string.

I'm using this code for parsing the JSON array. But this code is used for retrieving values from a JSON array, and I don't know how to get values from the above received JSON string.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse;

try {           
    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(status);

    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

    int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();

    Log.d("Json Array Length of status",String.valueOf(lengthJsonArr));

    for(int j1=0; j1 < lengthJsonArr; j1++) {

        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(j1);                      
        String addstatus=jsonChildNode.optString("slno").toString();
    }
 } catch(Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android). And if you don't want to parse every single JSON-object by yourself, you can use a JSON mapper library such as [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) or [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: In ur Json, slno is not there and ur trying to fetch the value and if it is not there. it may throw null and ur again doing toString. so ur app will crash. check before getting anything with jsonChildNode.has("slno") then u do ur logic in the braces

Comment: its a typo error brother

Comment: I take this from another code just to show you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
String s = "[{'AdsId':'7','AdsName':'PIC_01.JPG','AdsImage':'pic_01.jpg','AdsImageUrl':'http://www.google.com','TargetUrl':'http://www.yahoo.com','IsAllPageSupport':false,'IsArabic':false,'IsActive':true},{'AdsId':'8','AdsName':'PIC_02.JPG','AdsImage':'pic_02.jpg','AdsImageUrl':'http://www.fb.com','TargetUrl':'http://www.twitter.com','IsAllPageSupport':true,'IsArabic':false,'IsActive':true},{'AdsId':'9','AdsName':'PIC_03.JPG','AdsImage':'pic_03.jpg','AdsImageUrl':'http://www.google.com','TargetUrl':'http://www.demo.com','IsAllPageSupport':false,'IsArabic':false,'IsActive':true},{'AdsId':'10','AdsName':'PIC_04.JPG','AdsImage':'pic_04.jpg','AdsImageUrl':'http://www.sample.com','TargetUrl':'http://www.example.com','IsAllPageSupport':true,'IsArabic':false,'IsActive':true}]";
        JSONArray array;
        try {
            array = new JSONArray(s);

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                Log.v(i + "AdsId", array.getJSONObject(i)
                        .getString("AdsId"));
                Log.v(i + "AdsName",
                        array.getJSONObject(i).getString("AdsName"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Result

```
0AdsId: 7
0AdsName: PIC_01.JPG
1AdsId: 8
1AdsName: PIC_02.JPG
2AdsId: 9
2AdsName): PIC_03.JPG
3AdsId: 10
3AdsName: PIC_04.JPG
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create JSONArray object.

`JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(satus);
 //check the array is not empty and execute 
 ja.optJSONObject(0).optString("AdsId");`

Answer (score 0):

Easy way? Use a higher-level JSON object mapper like Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = mapper.readValue(status, ArrayList.class);
// You can now iterate over or randomly access the list
String adsName = list.get(0).get("AdsName");
```

If you want to do it without adding a custom library your code is a good start, but you have many issues in the code itself. Your use of Logging is wrong - the first parameter is the log tag (which is typically the class name), the second parameter the string to log. Try this:

```
try {

  final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(inputString);

  final int lengthJsonArr = jsonArray.length();

  Log.d("JSONParse", "Json Array Length of status " + lengthJsonArr);

  for(int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) {
    // This is an object from the array.
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // Retrieve any value from the object like this
    String adName = jsonChildNode.optString("AdsName").toString();
  }
} catch(Exception ex)
{
  Log.e("JSONParse", "Cannot read JSON string", ex);
}
```

Familiarize yourself with using Androids excellent Javadocs at developer.android.com, for example http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html